# Как задать движение объекта?

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton, qtimer

Как в *Python* задать движение объекта на *PyQt5*?

Предположим, у нас есть машина:

[image: Машина на стартовой позиции]

Нужно, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку "START" машина постепенно начала бы перемещаться вправо до примерно середины дороги (ну, можно на глаз).

---

У меня концепция была такая:

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.movement)

def movement(self):
    for i in range(0, 300, 100): 
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(i, 210, 151, 101))
```

Однако, после нажатия кнопки, машина почти моментально оказывается в финальной позиции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли это исправить?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предоставлять минимально-воспроизводимый пример - в ваших же интересах, да и наше время сэкономите.

Класс [**QTimer**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html) предоставляет повторяющиеся и однократные таймеры.

То что вы спрашиваете, может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.w = 800
        self.h = 400
        self.resize(self.w, self.h)
        
        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: #008080;')
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setFixedSize(QSize(70, 70))
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(70, 70))
        self.layoutH = QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.layoutH.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layoutH.addWidget(self.label, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)        
        
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('Button_2')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_clicked)
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.frame, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 
            alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)

        self.n = 0  
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()                                   # <----
        self.timer.setInterval(30)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.movement)
        
    def pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.n = 0 
        self.h = self.frame.geometry().height() // 2 - 35
        self.w = self.frame.geometry().width() // 2
        
        self.timer.start()                                             # <----
        
    def movement(self):
        self.label.move(self.n, self.h)
        self.n += 3
        if self.n > self.w:
            self.timer.stop()                                          # <----
            
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]